# Bluetooth scan response and inquiry response

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I was trying to understand basics of Bluetooth. I have few queries regarding the scanning and advertising of classic and low energy Bluetooth.

1. Where is EIR data (classic Bluetooth) filled in extended inquiry response stored?
   AFAIK AD data (Bluetooth low energy) is read from GAP profile. Where is data from GAP profile stored?
   When we enable advertising (low energy) using hcitool cmd or enable discoverable mode (classic Bluetooth), how does controller get all the advertisement information (scan response/ extended inquiry response)? Is it stored on controller?
2. Can same fields (e.g. device name) from EIR data and AD data be different ?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69159353/bluetooth-advertising-data